# Is there a way to map URLs to local files when debugging XML or XSLT files in Visual Studio?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, url, xslt, visual-studio-2017

Specifically, I have an .XSLT file that references other .XSLT files in a database, in this case utils.XSLT:

```
<xsl:include href="db://utils" />
```

I can't run or debug any .XSLT files that have these external references in Visual Studio alone, as I get this error:

```
XSLT compile error. The URI prefix is not recognized.
```

I'd like to provide a mapping somewhere in Visual Studio so a version of these external resources can be located (I will provide files on my local file system). 
I imagined some mapping might be described like this:

```
<uri name="db://utils" uri="D:\myCachedXslt\utils.xslt"     />
```

If this is possible it will significantly speed up my debugging & development workflow.

---

The closest I've found are [OASIS Catalogs](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/spec-2001-08-06.html#d0e263), but in VisualStudio I can only find support for [*Schema*Catalogs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255821.aspx#Anchor_0). SchemaCatalogs appear to be limited to re-mapping Schema (.XSD) files only, not general URLs in XML documents.

Comment: I've approached this by loading the XSL document, then changing the href attribute to point to a local file before running the transformation.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth that is what I might have to resort to. It just gets fiddly and is then something I have to remember to restore after testing.